# Two distinct answers to same integral?

Tags: integration

I am wonder if any integral has 2 answers which might not be equivalent.

As far as I know the integral:

∫sec²x tanx dx

has 2 answers using substitution:

When tanx=t

sex²xdx=dt

=∫tdt

=t²/2 + C

=tan²x/2 + C

When secx=t

=secxtanxdx=dt

=∫tdt

=t²/2 + C

=sec²x/2 + C

If both answers above are equivalent then please show it to me how?

Comment: Do you know how to prove $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$?

Comment: cos²x + sin²x=1  Divide by cos²x we get 1 + tan²x = sec²x

Comment: Congratulations, you have answered your own question! To show it, just replace $\frac{1}{2} \sec^2 x$ with $\frac{1}{2} \tan^2 x + 1$ and you will get $\frac{1}{2} \tan^2 x + C_1$.

Comment: ohhh! Thanks! I didn't think about this!

Comment: Differentiate both formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $C$ constant term in $ \frac{\tan^{2}x}{2} + C $ and $ \frac{\sec^{2}x}{2} + C $ need not be the same number, since these are solutions of an indefinite integral which is geometrically a family of curves - and they may refer to same or different curves depending on the value of their $C$s. It you are wondering how to arrive from one to the other, here is how you can do it:

$$ \frac{\tan^2x}{2} + C  = \frac{1}{2}.\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} + C $$
$$ \frac{\tan^2x}{2} + C = \frac{1}{2}.\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} +\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} + C $$
$$ \frac{\tan^2x}{2} + C = \frac{1}{2}.\Big(\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} +1\Big) -\frac{1}{2} + C $$
$$ \frac{\tan^2x}{2} + C = \frac{1}{2}.\Big(\frac{\sin^2x + \cos^2x}{\cos^2x}\Big) -\frac{1}{2} + C $$
and since, $\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}=1$, hence:
$$ \frac{\tan^2x}{2} + C = \frac{1}{2}.\Big(\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\Big) -\frac{1}{2} + C $$
$$ \frac{\tan^2x}{2} + C = \frac{\sec^2x}{2} -\frac{1}{2} + C $$
and $-\frac{1}{2}+C$ can be another constant, say $C_{2}$.
$$ \frac{\tan^2x}{2} + C = \frac{\sec^2x}{2} + C_{2} $$

So answering your original question - are they equivalent, **YES** they are!